# Access World Imagery Wayback in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am trying to access the ESRI World Imagery Wayback through a WMTS connection in QGIS 3.28.5.

I am using this URL: https://wayback.maptiles.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/world_imagery/mapserver/wmts/1.0.0/wmtscapabilities.xml.

All layers from 2014 - 2023 load in the Tileset-window when I connect. However, only the 2014-layers are displayed when added to the Layers-panel.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It's due to the "zoom" (layer's extent). First, you have to zoom-in into your AOI and then click in "Only versions with local changes"

[image: Trevelin, Argentina]

in this example I have zoomed into Trevelin (CH, ARG). There you'll see some dates (not all, only the ones available for that AOI). If you activate that layer in QGIS without zooming in you won't see the image, but if you zoom-in into that AOI you'll see it.